# Replace “ with " in eclipse?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

i am copying code from a pdf file , but when i paste it in eclipse it gives me errors cause the quotation mark is different than the one used in eclipse? Now in the XML file (android) when i use the search tool there is a replace button but when i paste the quotation mark from the book (“) in the box ("containing text") it is pasted as the one used in eclipse (") so that it turns out that i want to replace (") though i want to replace (“). Is there a way to do this replacement automatically (eg. by using the UTF code for the character)? Also when i paste the code it is aligned to the left. Is there a way for eclipse to automatically realign the code the way it should be (code inside classes, methods one tab to the left) ?

Comment: Have you tried to paste it first in text editor e.g. Notepad++ and replace the problematic character there first ?

Comment: Ctrl-i reindents the code. Ctrl-Shift-F reformats it.

Comment: ctrl+h to replace. ctrl+shift+f to format

Comment: Please update the question to add the solution or provide answer by yourself and close the question.

Comment: @Shaikh: do *not* advise to update the question! That would make it "not a question". The OP is free to add his current procedure as an *answer*, though.

Comment: @Jongware Thanks I have seen people rather updating the their own question to add the answer but I would advise now onwards to add new answer.